# Can I use java.util.LinkedList to construct a circular/cyclic linked list?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, circular-list

I would like to create a circular/cyclic linked list where the tail of the list would point back to the head of the list. So can I use `java.util.LinkedList` and modify the tail node after creation of the list to make it circular/cyclic? If so, can you show me some code on how that would happen?

If I can't use `java.util.LinkedList`, how should I create my own circular/cyclic linked list implementation? Can you show me the skeletons of how this implementation would look?

Let me know if you need more details and I'll clear up any confusion.

Comment: Why would you want a circular linked list?

Comment: I just want to play around with making one. No real reason except for myself. I haven't seen many implementations of this online and I just want to give it a try.

Comment: @puddingfox: A circular list is useful for round-robin access of a collection (e.g. for load-balancing)

Comment: @user359996: Is using a circular list for round robin just a good programming practise? I understand that 'round' and 'circular' go together, but are there any other reasons for using a circular list over an array list?

Comment: How the circular list is implemented isn't super important. To your point, I personally would use an ArrayList and then wrap it with http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#cycle(java.lang.Iterable). EDIT: Apparently, that's even one of the answers someone gave...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
class ListNode {
    public ListNode next;
    public Object data;

    public ListNode(Object data, ListNode next) {
        this.next = next;
        this.data = data;
    }
}

class CircularLinkedList {
    private ListNode head = null;
    private int numberOfElements = 0;
    private ListNode actualElement = null;
    private int index = 0;

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (numberOfElements == 0);
    }

    public int getNumberOfElements() {
        return numberOfElements;
    }

    public void insertFirst(Object data) {
        if (!(isEmpty())) {
            index++;
        }
        ListNode listNode = new ListNode(data, head);
        head = listNode;
        numberOfElements++;
    }

    public void insertAfterActual(Object data) {
        ListNode listNode = new ListNode(data, actualElement.next);
        actualElement.next = listNode;
        numberOfElements++;
    }

    public boolean deleteFirst() {
        if (isEmpty())
            return false;
        if (index > 0)
            index--;
        head = head.next;
        numberOfElements--;
        return true;
    }

    public boolean deleteActualElement() {
        if (index > 0) {
            numberOfElements--;
            index--;
            ListNode listNode = head;
            while (listNode.next.equals(actualElement) == false)
                listNode = listNode.next;
            listNode.next = actualElement.next;
            actualElement = listNode;
            return true;
        }
        else {
            actualElement = head.next;
            index = 0;
            return deleteFirst();
        }
    }

    public boolean goToNextElement() {
        if (isEmpty())
            return false;
        index = (index + 1) % numberOfElements;
        if (index == 0)
            actualElement = head;
        else
            actualElement = actualElement.next;
        return true;
    }

    public Object getActualElementData() {
        return actualElement.data;
    }

    public void setActualElementData(Object data) {
        actualElement.data = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: There were two minor bugs in the deleteActualElement method, I've corrected them.

Answer (score 13):

For practical application (e.g. not only playing around or learning) I would personally prefer Guava's `Iterables.cycle` method - see [`Iterables.cycle`](https://guava.dev/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#cycle-java.lang.Iterable-)

Answer (score 3):

java.util.LinkedList is one of the Collections datatypes.  The purpose of Collections is to provide utility structures, not bothering the programmer to worry about their internal implementation.  If you *must* have internals that work in a certain way, and the java.util ones do not guarantee that is how they work, then they are not for you.

To implement a circular linked list, first create a ListNode class:

```
class ListNode {
    ListNode next;
    ListNode prev;
    Object data;
}
```

Then store a `ListNode head`, and make sure `prev` of `head` points to the "end" of the list, and `next` of the "end" points back to `head`.  Honestly, though, there's little difference between a bidirectionally linked list keeping a tail pointer and a circular linked list.

Comment: I don't need a "bidirectional" linked list, so no need for `ListNode prev`. But thanks for your suggestion. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple solution using Deque. Pool last value from deque and insert it as first. This will cause cyclic roatation of values

```
Deque<String> circularStructure = new ArrayDeque();
circularStructure.addAll(List.of("Val1","Val2","Val3"));

for(i=0;i<100;i++){
   String value = typeCodeStack.pollLast(); //take and remove last
   typeCodeStack.push(code); //add as first
   //section where to use value 
   someOperationOnValue(value)
});
```